# Python Regex Capturing Group

Tags: python, regex

```
string1 = "abcdbcdbcde"
```

I want to extract string1 into three parts:
(first part and third part can be empty string)

first part:  a

second part (repeitions of some string):  bcdbcdbcd

third part: e

```
import re

string1 = "abcdbcdbcde"
m = re.match("(.*)(.+){2,}(.*)", string1)
print m.groups()[0], m.groups()[1], m.groups()[2]
```

Of cuz, the code above doesn't work.

As I know, parentheses operator can be used as RegEx capturing group or reference to the pattern. How to use the parentheses operator in these 2 cases at the same time?

What I want:

```
m.groups()[0] = "a"
m.groups()[1] = "bcdbcdbcd"
m.groups()[2] = "e"
```

Comment: Should the second part be a repetition of the same string? Like bcd bcd or like ab ab ab ab?

Answer (score 3):

If the second part should be a repetition of the same string, you could use an optional first a and third part. For the second part you could use a capturing group and a [back reference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html):

```
^.?(.+)\1+.?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/otLf24/1)

Or if you want all capturing groups:

```
^(.?)((.+)\3+)(.?)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(.?)` Group 1, optionally match any char
- `(` Group 2

  - `(.+)\3+` Group 3, match any char followed by a backreference to group 3 repeated 1+ gimes
- `)` Close group 3
- `(.?)` Group 4, optionally match any char
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/otLf24/2)

Answer (score 1):

My take on the problem:

```
import re

def match(s, m):
    m = re.match("(.*?)?((?:" + m + "){2,})(.*?)?$", s)
    return (m.groups()[0], m.groups()[1], m.groups()[2]) if m else (None, None, None)

print(match("abcdbcdbcde", "bcd"))
print(match("bcdbcdbcd", "bcd"))
print(match("abcdbcdbcd", "bcd"))
print(match("bcdbcdbcde", "bcd"))
print(match("axxbcdbcdxxe", "bcd"))
print(match("axxbcdxxe", "bcd")) # only one bcd in the middle
```

Prints:

```
('a', 'bcdbcdbcd', 'e')
('', 'bcdbcdbcd', '')
('a', 'bcdbcdbcd', '')
('', 'bcdbcdbcd', 'e')
('axx', 'bcdbcd', 'xxe')
(None, None, None)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is impossible to match exatcly your requirements, as more captuing groups are needed (at least to repeat matching same string with `\1`).

But you can try `(\w+)((\w+)\3+)(\w+)`

It will consists of 4 capturing groups. Generally, first capturing group will contain `a` and last will contain `e`, second will contain repeated string, rest are irrelevant.

Explanation:

`\w+` - match one or more of word characters

`\3+` - match string captured in third capturing group, one ore more times

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IbY0eB/3)

Answer (score 0):

The following regex should work (caveat below):

```
^(.*?)((.+?)\3+)(.*)
```

**Explanation:**

```
^      # Start of string
(.*?)  # Match any number of characters, as few as possible, until...
(      # (Start capturing group #2)
 (.+?) # ... a string is matched (and captured in group #3)
 \3+   # that is repeated at least once.
)      # End of group #2
(.*)   # Match the rest of the string
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/v3HTcm/1).

Caveat: If the string is long and doesn't have any obvious repeats, this is going to have very bad performance characteristics (`O(n!)`, I think), since the regex engine has to check each and every permutation of substrings. See [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).